# Insert missing datetime in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a `pd.DataFrame`

```
    utc_time            year  month day weekday hour
0   2017-01-01 21:00:00 2017    1   1   7   21
1   2017-01-01 23:00:00 2017    1   1   7   23
2   2017-01-02 00:00:00 2017    1   2   1   0
3   2017-01-02 01:00:00 2017    1   2   1   1
```

In the `df` above, hour `22` doesn't show up. I want every hour include in the dataframe, like:

```
    utc_time            year  month day weekday hour
0   2017-01-01 21:00:00 2017    1   1   7   21
0   2017-01-01 22:00:00 2017    1   1   7   22
1   2017-01-01 23:00:00 2017    1   1   7   23
2   2017-01-02 00:00:00 2017    1   2   1   0
3   2017-01-02 01:00:00 2017    1   2   1   1
```

How to build function to detect the missing hour and insert into the dataframe ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill the missing hour Values in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069515/how-to-fill-the-missing-hour-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC `resample` +`bfill` and `ffill`

```
s=df.set_index('utc_time').resample('1H')
(s.ffill()+s.bfill())/2
Out[163]: 
                     year  month  day  weekday  hour
utc_time                                            
2017-01-01 21:00:00  2017      1    1        7    21
2017-01-01 22:00:00  2017      1    1        7    22
2017-01-01 23:00:00  2017      1    1        7    23
2017-01-02 00:00:00  2017      1    2        1     0
2017-01-02 01:00:00  2017      1    2        1     1
```